# Summing large amounts of data on mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, database

Im looking for the most efficient way of performing summing queries against mongodb.

Currently we insert documents that contain various information and a date time stamp of when the document was created.

We need to sum this data to be viewed in the following ways:

Documents by hour of the day 1-24
Documents by day of the month 1-28/31
Documents by month of the year 1-12
Documents by year

This summed data will be accessed often as we're afraid that the massive amount of data thrown at mongo will have problems summing this data often.

We thought perhaps when a document is inserted into mongo that we have another document that contains these counts that we increment at the time of insertion. This way, we can quickly pull the counts without summing the data each request. Our concern is that this may not be the most efficient way to perform this type of operation in mongo

Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this? My dev team as well as myself are new to mongodb and we want to make sure we don't fall into a performance trap with summing large sets of data.

Comment: You seem to have a workable solution, and whether or not it's the *most* efficient way, it should certainly handle the "massive summing" issue.  Sounds like the only real potential for inefficiency is if you were adding documents fast enough that opening, modifying, and saving the "totals" document got to be a significant cost.  Why not implement what you've come up with and then test?

Comment: That's what we'll probably go with. Wasn't sure if there was a much better way of handling situations like this

Comment: This option boils down your per-read access cost to "Open document.  Read Document."  (while adding "Open document.  Read Document.  Write Document." to your Add costs).  Speaking as someone who has no experience whatsoever with mongodb, I'm doubting that that cost is all that high.  If it *is* too high, the real answer is to go with the same plan, but find somewhere with faster access to store it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation) is perfectly suited for this type of queries.
I've done some examples for you below.

To start, let's populate some documents:

> db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new Date('01/01/2012'),
>   "topic" : "My Title 1"}); db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new
>   Date('01/02/2012'), "topic" : "My Title 2"});
>   db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new Date('01/02/2012'),
>   "topic" : "My Title 3"}); db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new
>   Date('01/02/2012'), "topic" : "My Title 4"});
>   db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new Date('01/04/2012'),
>   "topic" : "My Title 5"}); db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new
>   Date('01/05/2012'), "topic" : "My Title 6"});
>   db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new Date('01/07/2013'),
>   "topic" : "My Title 7"}); db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new
>   Date('01/07/2013'), "topic" : "My Title 8"});
>   db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new Date('02/07/2013'),
>   "topic" : "My Title 9"}); db.myDocumentCollection.insert({"date" : new
>   Date('02/08/2013'), "topic" : "My Title 10"});

**Return number of documents grouped by full date**

```
db.myDocumentCollection.group(
{
   $keyf : function(doc) {
       return { "date" : doc.date.getDate()+"/"+doc.date.getMonth()+"/"+doc.date.getFullYear() };
    },
    initial: {count:0},
    reduce: function(obj, prev) { prev.count++; }
 })
```

**Output**

```
[
        {
                "date" : "1/0/2012",
                "count" : 1
        },
        {
                "date" : "2/0/2012",
                "count" : 3
        },
        {
                "date" : "4/0/2012",
                "count" : 1
        },
        {
                "date" : "5/0/2012",
                "count" : 1
        },
        {
                "date" : "7/0/2013",
                "count" : 2
        },
        {
                "date" : "7/1/2013",
                "count" : 1
        },
        {
                "date" : "8/1/2013",
                "count" : 1
        }
]
```

**Return number of documents grouped by day of month for the year 2013**

This is perhaps a little more relevant for the kinds of queries you want to do.
Here, we use the `cond` to specify only to group documents after 1/1/2013
You could use `$gte` and `$lte` to do date ranges here.

```
db.myDocumentCollection.group(
{
   $keyf : function(doc) {
       return { "date" : doc.date.getDate()+"/"+doc.date.getMonth()};
    },
    cond: {"date" : {"$gte": new Date('01/01/2013')}},
    initial: {count:0},
    reduce: function(obj, prev) { prev.count++; }
 })
```

**Output**

```
[
        {
                "date" : "7/0",
                "count" : 2
        },
        {
                "date" : "7/1",
                "count" : 1
        },
        {
                "date" : "8/1",
                "count" : 1
        }
]
```

Comment: ... I didn't realise until I'd posted my answer this question was asked in May!